# Changing the pitch of a speaking voice with JavaScript and html

Tags: javascript, html

I can change the speed of playback of a recording of a speaking voice very easily and effectively by using .playbackRate on an Audio tag . Is there any way to change the pitch of the voice during playback.

Comment: According to http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#L15842 there should be a .setVelocity method. Have you search around for "javascript audio pitch" or similar queries?

Comment: Thank you John D. I looked at the specification and I think it means that

Comment: I think it means that we can change the speed of the listener moving away from or towards the sound source and that would change the apparent frequency of the source sound. Does that sound correct to you?

Comment: Thank you horch260. I have not tried anything yet. I am trying to get an idea of the best direction to go in.

Answer (score 4):

I've used pitch-shifter.js from this project for pitch shifting. It seemed to work pretty well. https://github.com/urtzurd/html-audio

However, that script uses the web audio API, which is a fair bit more complicated than just using audio tags.

Comment: Thank-you Raphael. I have worked a little with the API. I have looked at the code you suggest and can see the possibilities, but it will take me some time, at my level of expertise, to tease out the relevant parts.